# Wrong results for round() in Arduino IDE at ATMega328P

Tags: c, arduino-ide, atmega32

I get an unexpected result when using round():

```
#include <Arduino.h>
int main(void) {
  init();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  float a = 1.0;
  float b = round(a);
  Serial.println(b);  // prints "1.50" 
  delay(100);
  return 0;
}
```

What is the trick to get the expected value `1.0`?

Comment: Assuming this is C++, did you include the headers declaring round() and Serial? Enabled support for floating point (if it is needed on your OS)? Can you show us a complete, minimal program?

Comment: @Jens I included the full code example

Comment: Embedded bare metal program with `main` ending with `return 0`?? Hm. It can't end well.

Comment: Please replace `b` with `"Hello world"` and see it is printing it. Maybe you don't compile/flash the code properly.

Comment: @EugeneSh. It prints the same result if I remove the `return 0` or run the code in an endless loop …

Comment: Endless loop is the usual mode of operation for these things. If you "terminate" the program - it might do weird stuff.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The code compiles properly and is also flashed. Changing `a = 1.0` to `a = 66.0` results into "66.50"

Comment: Please replace with text as I suggested. If it prints as expected, replace with hardcoded `66.0f` inside the `println`

Answer (score 1):

It seems I found the problem:
The issue is caused by the `round()` macro in Arduino.h:

```
#define round(x)     ({ typeof (x) _x = (x); _x >= 0 ? (long)_x + 0.5 : (long)_x - 0.5; })
```

You have to cast the `round()` result to an integer type to get the expected float:

```
float a = 1.0f;
float b = (int16_t) round(a);
Serial.println(b);  // "1.00"
```

Comment: Whoa - this is super confusing, especially as there is already a [round()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) stnadard function. I suggest to use `float b = roundf(a);`. I got to [this comment in github issue](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-API/issues/76#issuecomment-304721366). It would be great if they would remove the macro - it is in conflict with standard function.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks for the github link, I posted a comment there 

Comment: This is a problem of Arduino long debated, **a bug for me** anyway. If you need the real `round()`, after the header inclusion undefine the macro `#undef round`, then include `math.h`.